Existence of ergodic subgroup invariant to a product measure
Let $X=\{0, 1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$ and $G$ be the group of permutations, each of which only permutes finitely many coordinates of $X$. Fix a sequence $(\lambda_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subseteq (0, 1]$ and for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define $\mu_n(0) = \dfrac{1}{1+\lambda_n}$, $\mu_n(1) = \dfrac{\lambda_n}{1+\lambda_n}$. Put $\mu = \otimes_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\mu_n$ that is defined on the $\sigma$-algebra generated by cylinder sets of $X$. For every $g\in G$, define $g\mu$ by $(g\mu)(A) = \mu\big( g^{-1}A \big)$ for every measurable subset $A\subseteq X$. Define the full group of $G$ as the following:
$$
[G]= \big\{\varphi:X\rightarrow X\,\vert\, \varphi\,\text{ invertible, measurable and }\forall\,x\in X,\, \varphi(x)\in Gx \big\}
$$
For each $\varphi\in [G]$, define $\varphi\mu$ the same way we define $g\mu$ for each $g\in G$. Now suppose $0$ is a cluster point of $(\lambda_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\mu$ has no atoms. Then can we find a product measure $\sigma$ and $H$ an ergodic subgroup of $[G]$ such that $\sigma$ is $H$-invariant, namely $h\sigma=\sigma$ for each $h\in H$?
I came up with this question when trying to show if $[G]$ is generated by $G$ itself and all the "$+1$"-addition with carry-over (namely the odometer that starts from the $N$-th coordinate where $N$ ranges over all $\mathbb{N}$). I believe $\mu$ cannot be invariant to an odometer that starts with $N$-th coordinate unless $\lambda_n=1$ for all $n\geq N$. The condition "$0$ is a cluster point of $(\lambda_n)$" makes it impossible for $\mu$ to be invariant to any odometers or elements in $G$. If the desired $H$ exists, then it shows that $[G]$ is much larger than I thought and, instead of $\mu$ itself, I am looking for $\sigma$ that is equivalent to $\mu$ and hopefully that would make it easier to find the desired $H$.
Update: By "$[G]$ is generated by $G$ and $(T_N)_{N\in\mathbb{N}}$", I mean to ask if every element in $[G]$ can be written as a composition of finitely many elements from the set $G\cup \{T_N\}_{N\in \mathbb{N}}$ where each $T_N$ is the "$+1$"-addtion with carry-over that starts from $N$-th coordinate. If you need a topology for $[G]$, first consider the following metric for $X$:
$$
\forall\,x, y \in X, \hspace{0.5cm} d(x, y) = \sum_{i\in\mathbb{N}} \frac{x_i-y_i}{2^i}
$$
and then given $\varphi, \psi\in [G]$, define:
$$
D(\varphi, \psi) = \sup_{x\in X}d\big( \varphi(x), \psi(x) \big)
$$
So far as I have seen $D$ is the canonical one for $[G]$ but please feel free to use a different topology if necessary.

Crossposted at Mathematics.SE.

My bad .... I mentioned this post in MS but forgot to do the same here ...
